# Java converting UTF-8 Text to ASCII produces weird output

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, ascii

I'm trying to convert the content of a plain text file (UTF-8) into ASCII (ISO-8859-15) to write it to an output file. I've written a few lines of code (see below) which read the content of the file, write it to an array of bytes, decode it with the UTF-8 charset, encode it with the ISO-8859-15 Charset and write the result to a file. This works just fine, except for a question mark (Hx: 3F) that suddenly appears at the very beginning of the output file.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.CharBuffer;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

public class Main {



  public static void main(String[] args) {

/* Read / write the file to a byte array */

    File input = new File("input.txt");
    byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) input.length()];
    try (FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream(input)){
      fileInput.read(bytes);
    } catch(IOException e) {
      if(e instanceof FileNotFoundException) {
        System.err.println("File not found.");
      } else {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
/* Getting the charsets */
    Charset utf8charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
    Charset iso885915charset = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-15");

/* Wrapping the bytes from the file into a buffer */
    ByteBuffer inputBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);
/* Encoding the text file from UTF-8 */
    CharBuffer data = utf8charset.decode(inputBuffer);

/* Decoding the text file to ISO-8859-15 and writing it to an array*/
    ByteBuffer outputBuffer = iso885915charset.encode(data);

    byte[] outputData = outputBuffer.array();
    System.out.println(new String(outputData));

    File output = new File("output.txt");

/* Writing the output to a file */
    try(BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(output))) {
      out.write(outputData);
      out.close();
    } catch(IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

> Input file:
>
> ABC
>
> DEF
>
> GHI
>
> Output file:
>
> ?ABC
>
> DEF
>
> GHI

If you have an idea, what might be the cause of this weird behavior, please let me know. Also, if there is anything weird about my code in general, please point it out to me, since I'm not very experienced in the use of Java yet.

Thanks :)

Comment: I am running the same code, which is producing the expected output i.e. without `?` in it.

Comment: @procrastinator I tried it in a new project and it worked too. Very weird, but it seems something is wrong with the project I have been using for this code. Thanks for your support :)

Comment: In order of learning about character encoding I now found out about the byte order marks. It seems that the microsoft notepad is using the UTF-8 encoding with those, even though they are not needed anymore. When converting from UTF-8 to ASCII the BOM then gets turned into a question mark.